# Type annotation missing in pattern in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I get the error "Type annotation missing in pattern" when declaring a variable as follows:

```
var total
```

What is type annotation?

Comment: Edit your question to show the error properly

Answer (score 30):

Type annotation is the following:

```
var total:Int
```

The ":Int" is the type annotation.  This must be used when you don't set a value (thus having an implied type) at the time of declaration.

If you were to define your variable as follows:

```
var total = 9
```

You would no longer need to explicitly annotate the type at the time of declaration.